# Fix general bug while on feature branch

Tags: git

I try to improve my workflow with git.

To develop a new feature, I created a `myFeature` branch based on my `Dev` branch.

While working on this feature, I found a general bug in my application. I'd like to commit my fix in the `Dev` branch but I wrote the fix while on `myFeature` branch, so git forbids me to switch branch until I commit the fix to the current branch

```
git checkout dev
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
```

is there a way I can commit this fix without copying the file out of my git repo, do a `git checkout --` on it, change to `Dev` branch and copy the fixed file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two ways to do this:

1. `git stash` -> `git checkout Dev` -> `git stash pop` -> `git commit`
2. `git commit` generates SHA-> `git checkout Dev` -> `git cherry-pick SHA`

For both solutions you would do `git checkout myFeature` -> `git rebase Dev` afterwards.

Comment: why `git stash pop` and not `git stash drop` ?

Comment: @IggY Because you want to apply the changes to the `Dev` branch. `git stash drop` just deletes your fix.

Answer (score 1):

Stash the changes (which essentially creates an anonymous commit) so that the working directory is clean. Then change branches, apply the stash to the new branch, and commit.

```
git stash
git checkout dev
git stash pop
```

`git stash pop` has the potential for something like a merge commit; you'll need to resolve those if necessary, but then you can `git add` and `git commit` as usual.

Comment: why `git stash drop` as, according to Nils_M comment under its answer, it would delete the fix ?

Comment: Because the two words are too similar and I wrote the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is a cherry pick commit.

First run

```
git log
```

then get the hash of the commit where your fix is

checkout your target branch (in your case Dev)

```
git checkout <yourTargetBranch>
```

and apply the cherry pick command over the hash of your commit.

```
git cherry-pick <commitHash>
```

Check this link where your case is explained in detail.

https://ariejan.net/2010/06/10/cherry-picking-specific-commits-from-another-branch/